# send email verfication link using django-email-verification with celery

Tags: python, django, email, celery, email-verification

I am using django-email-verification for sending verification link to email of the user but it tales time to send email , i want to send mail with celery for the same to speed it up , please guide me how can i add celery configs?

Answer (score 0):

Celery isn't going to make this run any faster. What Celery will do for you is make the task asynchronous.